# Deezer API - get current position

Tags: javascript, playback, deezer

I want to track when a user starts playing a song. My Problem is that it is only possible to track the *play Button* (in my opinion). But I only want the beginning of the song and not every Play Button click (also when the user has pause the song and resume it).

Therefore I wanna check the current position of the song and track only when the current position is below 1 second or something. Does anyone know how to get the position of the current playing song? The only thing regarding the player position I have found was the *player_position* event which is triggered when the position within the song has changed.

Any ideas? The very last I want to do is to store a variable that remembers, if the song was already tracked or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know when an user has started to play a song is to use the "player_position" as you said. It is different than the "player_play" which is executed when you use the "DZ.player.play" action. If you want, you have an example here http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/example-invisible which displays how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint of Fred_Dzr I made a solution, that works quite nice:

```
DZ.Event.subscribe('player_position', function(positionArray) {
    var track = DZ.player.getCurrentTrack();
    var position = Math.floor(positionArray[0]);
    if(position === 1) {
        if(!track['tracked']) {
            console.log('TRACKING: play: ' + track.id + ' | ' + track.artist.name + ' - ' + track.title);
            track['tracked'] = true;
        }
    } else {
        track['tracked'] = false;
    }
});
```

With the additional flag "tracked" on every track I am sure that the Song is not tracked twice, when the "player_position" Event is fired on position 1.1593044475699572 and 1.4754669253862243 and 1.7916924465679582 or something else.

Tracking on position 0 don't work for me, because the "player_position" Event is fired on player load, but position 1 is quite enough. Also when the User seeks to the beginning of the song the tracking is triggered. Thats ok, because in this case he listen to the Song again.

With this method I am also able to track the Midpoint of the Song.

Thank you!